# NullPointerException ao executar ListView.setAdapter (Android)

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

eu estou implementando uma aplicação onde preciso exibir uma lista de Cães (já cadastrada no BD) e permitir que ao clicar num item da lista, seja exibida uma nova activy para editar os dados.

O problema é que estou recebendo um NullPointerException quando tento executar o setAdapter. Usando o debug percebi que durante toda a execução, a minha ListView que criei para receber a referência do layout permanece como null, mesmo após usar o findViewByID... Alguém consegue ajudar nisto? Seguem abaixo o Layout e a Activity:

```
package br.fatec.projeto.passeiacao;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class VerCaesActivity extends Activity{

    ListView listaCaes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listaCaes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaCaesId);

        CaoDAO dao = new CaoDAO (this);
        List <Cao> caes = dao.obterLista ();

        ArrayAdapter <Cao> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <Cao> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, caes);

        listaCaes.setAdapter(adapter);

        listaCaes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

E abaixo o Layout desta Activity:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaCaesId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

Desde já, agradeço se puderem ajudar!

Comment: Galera, resolvi meu problema acrescentando um setContentView no meu onCreate.

setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_caes);

Aparentemente sem esta informação o Android não sabia qual era o layout que deveria ser utilizado.

Comment: `setContentView()` serve para isso mesmo: informar qual o layout que a Acticity deve usar.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou o `setContentView(R.layout.NomeDoSeuLayout);`, o Android não consegue encontrar a sua lista porque ele não sabe em qual layout procurar.